# How can I add all previous cells to a cell using a function in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If I have a column:

0  |

1  |

2  |

3  |

4  |

I would like for in the column on the right to take a cell on the left and add all previous cells to it. So that it looks like the two columns below:

0 |   0

1 |   1

2 |  3

3 |  6

4 |  10

I've tried manually adding each but I know there must be a function that can accomplish this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the first column starts in A1, B1 could contain:

```
=SUM(A$1:A1)
```

Copy that down the column as needed.

Comment: +1 for your answer, but, if the numbers in the first column start at `0` or `1`, and they are consecutive, the second column is actually a triangle number, and there is a specific formula for that: `(X*X/2)+(X/2)`. I only point this out because the whole column thing may be unnecessary if the goal is to get the triangle number of an arbitrary number; all the columns and formulae could be reduced to a single cell.

Comment: @RonMaupin: Good catch.  It isn't clear whether that would answer what the OP is looking for, but it could be useful to post as an answer that might be generally useful.

Comment: I will post it as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are looking to use these two columns in a lookup to get the sum of all the previous numbers in a consecutive order which starts with `0` or `1`, that can be accomplished with a single formula. Such a total is called a triangle number, and the formula for that is `(x^2)/2 + (x/2)`.

Due to the comment, the Excel version of the formula (assuming the source value to convert is in `A1`) is `=(A1^2/2)+(A1/2)`.

If that is your goal, the formula is a much more elegant solution.

Comment: I might upvote this if it actually contained an Excel function to do the calculation.  As it is, I'm tempted to flag it as "not an answer".

Comment: @G-Man, Sorry. I added the Excel version.I copied the formula directly from a test in an Excel spreadsheet.  The reason I gave the raw formula was that I don't have any reference for which cell(s) may be used as the source. There really is no difference, other than the `=`. I would think that anyone using Excel could take a formula and use it in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Not sure if I am just implementing it incorrectly but this did not work for me. So in the left column each cell is supposed to represent the meters I have walked from a point. First I walked 0 meters, from there I walked 1 meter, from there I walked 2 more meters, etc. Then, the right column is supposed to be meters walked thus far, so all the previous cells on the left are added together, if that makes sense?

Comment: @Jay, The formula I gave you only works if the number of meters walked is a series of consecutive numbers, starting with `0` or `1`. You could just then enter the last number, and it will give you the sum of all the consecutive numbers up to, and including, the number you entered. Otherwise, use the answer given by @fixer1234. We didn't have your application for the use of the solution.

Comment: Got it, I should have just used some of the actual data because they're not increasing consecutively like that, the method by @fixer1234 worked, thank you for the help otherwise.